# Zurb Foundation 5 - responsive tables and dropdown buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

When trying to use a drop down or split drop down button inside a TD cell with the zurb foundation responsive tables, the following happens:

HTML on browser (works as expected)
IPAD (works as expected)
IPhone (the dropdown hides within the TD element and is not clickable)

Code:

```
  <td class="text-center">
   <a href="#" class="tiny round button split">Actions<span data-dropdown="drop"></span></a><br>
     <ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
       <li><%= link_to show_image, cancellation %></li>
       <li><%= link_to edit_image, edit_cancellation_path(cancellation) %></li>
       <li><%= link_to delete_image, cancellation, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
     </ul>
   </td>
```

The responsive table format is the one shown here:  [Crafty Responsive Tables Playground](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables)

Any suggestions?

I'm trying to place the default show/edit/destroy actions normally associated with common rails tables in a dropdown button.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old yet still applies as I just ran into this issue with dropdown buttons not working on iPads (any generation).

After some googling I found [a solution that worked](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/685-foundation-5-top-bar-dropdown):

> The change discribed here solved the ipad drop down menu problem.
>
> I chaged code from
>
> ```
> <li class='has-dropdown not-click'>
>     <a>Menu dropdown</a>
>     <ul class='dropdown'>
>           <li><a href='aulas.php'>Aulas</a></li>
>           <li><a href='locais.php'>Locais</a></li>
>     </ul>
> </li>
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> <li class='has-dropdown not-click'>
>     <a href='#'>Menu dropdown</a>
>     <ul class='dropdown'>
>          <li><a href='aulas.php'>Aulas</a></li>
>          <li><a href='locais.php'>Locais</a></li>
>     </ul>
> </li>
> ```
>
> **lack of href='#' was the cause in my case.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a simple CSS problem. If the dropdown is still working but hiding behind another element, try writing a CSS rule for the td that sets its z-index higher.

If its containing element has a z-index set though, this might not work, so you could try using CSS again to remove any z-index rule.

[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: I've tested this and it does not make a difference.  I've verified that the indexes hold but that they don't bring the content to the front.